# xpath wrong using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get `Fax number` but they gave me nothing these is page link https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire-des-avocats/stephanie-dreux/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire-des-avocats/stephanie-dreux/'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

Fax = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p//strong[contains(text(),'Fax : ')]").text
print(Fax)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to locate `strong` tag but you need a `p` tag:

```
Fax = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[strong[contains(text(),'Fax : ')]]").text
print(Fax.strip('Fax : '))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by JaSON you need to locate the `p` tag element.
Also you need to use a `WebDriverWait` to wait for visibility of that element.
As following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://www.barreaunantes.fr/annuaire-des-avocats/stephanie-dreux/'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

fax = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[strong[contains(text(),'Fax : ')]]"))).text
print(fax.strip('Fax : '))
```